# How to search through serverside processing datatables where some columns are from foreign key values?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, server-side

I have successfully loaded the table content from serverside using datatables serverside processing. But when i search for a value in the table that was picked from another database table using its foreign key. The results are empty.
i.e. i have a products_table and the stock_table where the stock table references the pid as the product id of which the name is the one displayed in my datatable. But i can't search the product yet its showing in the datatable?

Can anyone help me out here thanks.

`

```
public function GetStockRecords()
{
        $table      = 'tbl_stock';
        $primaryKey     = 'st_id';



        $columns = array(
            array( 'db' => 'st_id',  'dt' => 0 ),
            array(  'db' => 'st_pid',
                    'dt' => 1,
                    'formatter' => function($d, $row){
                        $product =    $this->GeneralModel->get_product($row['st_pid']);
                        return $product['pr_name'];
                    }
                ),
            array(  'db' => 'st_quantity',
                    'dt' => 2,
                    'formatter' => function($d, $row){
                        $units = $this->GeneralModel->get_unit($row['st_unit']);
                        return '<b>' . $row['st_quantity'] . '</b> <i>' . $units['un_name'] . '</i>';
                    }
                 ),
            array(  'db' => 'st_type',
                    'dt' => 3,
                    'formatter' => function($d, $row){
                        $state         = '';
                        if($row['st_type'] == 'PURCHASE')
                        {
                            $state = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-success"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="color:#ffffff;"></i>  PURCHASE</a>';
                        }
                        else if($row['st_type'] == 'TRANSFER')
                        {
                            $state = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-success"><i class="fa fa-exchange" style="color:#ffffff;"></i>  TRANSFER</a>';
                        }
                        else if($row['st_type'] == 'SALE')
                        {
                            $state = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-success"><i class="fa fa-money" style="color:#ffffff;"></i>  SALE</a>';
                        }

                        return $state;
                    }
                 ),
            array(
                    'db' => 'st_origin_type',
                    'dt' => 4,
                    'formatter' => function($d, $row){
                        $origin        = '';

                        if($row['st_origin_type'] == 'CLIENT')
                        {
                            $or       = $this->GeneralModel->get_client($row['st_origin']);
                            $origin   = ucwords(strtolower($or['cl_name']));
                        }
                        else if($row['st_origin_type'] == 'BRANCH')
                        {
                            $or       = $this->GeneralModel->get_branch($row['st_origin']);
                            $origin   = '<a href="'.site_url("general/branchdetail/". $or['br_id']).'">'.ucwords(strtolower($or['br_name'])).'</a>';
                        }
                        else if($row['st_origin_type'] == 'SUPPLIER')
                        {
                            $or       = $this->GeneralModel->get_supplier($row['st_origin']);
                            $origin   = ucwords(strtolower($or['su_name']));
                        }
                        else if($row['st_origin_type'] == 'STORE')
                        {
                            $or       = $this->GeneralModel->get_store($row['st_origin']);
                            $origin   = '<a href="'.site_url("general/storedetail/". $or['br_id']).'">'.ucwords(strtolower($or['br_name'])).'</a>';
                        }
                        return $origin;
                    }
                 )
        );

        // SQL server connection information
        $sql_details = array(
            'user' => $this->db->username,
            'pass' => $this->db->password,
            'db'   => $this->db->database,
            'host' => $this->db->hostname
        );

        $whereResult = '';

        echo json_encode(
            SSP::complex ( $_POST, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult, $whereAll=null )
        );
    }



//Javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TableAdvanced = function() {

        var initTable2 = function() {
            var table = $('#sample_2');

            /* Table tools samples: https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/ */

            /* Set tabletools buttons and button container */

            $.extend(true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
                "container" : "btn-group tabletools-btn-group pull-right",
                "buttons" : {
                    "normal" : "btn btn-sm default",
                    "disabled" : "btn btn-sm default disabled"
                },
                    "searching" : true,
                    "ordering" : true
            });

            var oTable = table.dataTable({

                // Internationalisation. For more info refer to http://datatables.net/manual/i18n
                "language" : {
                    "aria" : {
                        "sortAscending" : ": activate to sort column ascending",
                        "sortDescending" : ": activate to sort column descending"
                    },
                    "emptyTable" : "No data available in table",
                    "info" : "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
                    "infoEmpty" : "No entries found",
                    "infoFiltered" : "(filtered1 from _MAX_ total entries)",
                    "lengthMenu" : "Show _MENU_ entries",
                    "search" : "Search:",
                    "zeroRecords" : "No matching records found"
                },

                    "serverSide" : "true",
                    "processing" : "true",
                    "ajax" : {
                         "url" : "<?= site_url('inventory/getstockrecords'); ?>",
                         "type" : "POST"
                    },
                "order" : [[0, 'desc']],
                "lengthMenu" : [[5, 15, 20, -1], [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
                ],

                // set the initial value
                "pageLength" : 15,
                "dom" : "<'row' <'col-md-12'T>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>", // horizobtal scrollable datatable

                // Uncomment below line("dom" parameter) to fix the dropdown overflow issue in the datatable cells. The default datatable layout
                // setup uses scrollable div(table-scrollable) with overflow:auto to enable vertical scroll(see: assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js).
                // So when dropdowns used the scrollable div should be removed.
                //"dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'T>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",

                "tableTools" : {
                    "sSwfPath" : "<?= base_url(); ?>assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                    "aButtons" : [{
                        "sExtends" : "pdf",
                        "sButtonText" : "PDF"
                    }, {
                        "sExtends" : "csv",
                        "sButtonText" : "CSV"
                    }, {
                        "sExtends" : "xls",
                        "sButtonText" : "Excel"
                    }, {
                        "sExtends" : "print",
                        "sButtonText" : "Print",
                        "sInfo" : 'Please press "CTRL+P" to print or "ESC" to quit',
                        "sMessage" : "Powered By Buzen Technologies"
                    }, {
                        "sExtends" : "copy",
                        "sButtonText" : "Copy"
                    }]
                }
            });

            var tableWrapper = $('#sample_2_wrapper');
            // datatable creates the table wrapper by adding with id {your_table_jd}_wrapper
            tableWrapper.find('.dataTables_length select').select2();
            // initialize select2 dropdown
        }
        return {

            init : function() {

                if (!jQuery().dataTable) {
                    return;
                }

                initTable2();
            }
        };

    }();
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show some code please? How you load the table content, what you tried, what do you want to achieve, etc. ?

Comment: Hi Robert: It's better to put the code in your question, and format it correctly, than to put it in a comment.

Comment: I have added the code in the question thanks @KIKOSoftware

Comment: See: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side Have you used the `search` parameter correctly? It is send to the PHP files that returns the serverside data. I cannot find it in your code.

Comment: i set searching to true `"searching" : true` ... Which search parameters exactly? Do i need to post values that i need to search?